# Asynchronous Socket Reading

Tags: android, sockets

I am new to Java / Android development, and I am now trying to find my way around some network IO, specifically over sockets.

I am trying to work out the best way of achieving the functionality where I open a socket connection to the server, and keep it open for the server to post unsolicited data to my client. I can implement a command-response model relatively easily in a separate thread using AsyncTask.

Is there a way to do an asynchronous read on an open Socket in Android (in .Net I used Socket.BeginReceive to achieve this). Or failing that, is there a blocking socket read that I can put in a worker thread, whilst allowing the main thread to write to the same socket whilst the read is blocked?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html).getInputStream().read() can be used in your AsyncTask. It blocks.

Socket.getOutpuStream().write() can be put in your main thread and will work fine if the read is blocking in another thread.